# I got an error while displaying data in dependent drop down in real time database using flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

class homepg extends StatelessWidget {
const homepg({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("home"),
  ),
  body: MyHomePage(),
);
 }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
 }

 class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 var ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
 var _selectedexam;
 var _selectedsemester;

 var _selectedcourse;

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Container(
     margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
     child: Center(
      child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: [
            const Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text(
                "Exam ",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 40,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 400,
              child: FutureBuilder(
                  future: ref.child("/Exam").get(),
                  builder:
                      (context, AsyncSnapshot<DataSnapshot> asyncSnapshot) {
                    if (asyncSnapshot.hasError)
                      return Text("Error: ${asyncSnapshot.error}");
                    if (!asyncSnapshot.hasData)
                      return const CircularProgressIndicator();

                    return DropdownButton<String>(
                      isExpanded: true,
                      items: asyncSnapshot.data!.children
                          .map((snap) => DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: snap.key,
                              child: Text(snap.key.toString())))
                          .toList(),
                      value: _selectedexam,
                      onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                        setState(() {
                          _selectedexam = newValue!;
                          print(_selectedexam);
                        });
                      },
                    );
                  }),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 100,
        ),
        Row(
          children: [
            const Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text(
                  "Semester",
                  style:
                      TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18),
                )),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 20,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 400,
              child: FutureBuilder(
                  future: ref.child("/Exam/$_selectedexam").get(),
                  builder:
                      (context, AsyncSnapshot<DataSnapshot> asyncSnapshot) {
                    if (asyncSnapshot.hasError)
                      return Text("Error: ${asyncSnapshot.error}");
                    if (!asyncSnapshot.hasData)
                      return const CircularProgressIndicator();

                    return DropdownButton<String>(
                      isExpanded: true,
                      items: asyncSnapshot.data!.children
                          .map((snap) => DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: snap.key,
                              child: Text(snap.key.toString())))
                          .toList(),
                      value: _selectedsemester,
                      onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                        setState(() {
                          //_selectedexam = null;
                          _selectedsemester = newValue!;
                          print(_selectedsemester);
                        });
                      },
                    );
                  }),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 100,
        ),
        Row(
          children: [
            const Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text(
                  "Course",
                  style:
                      TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18),
                )),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 40,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 400,
              child: FutureBuilder(
                  future: ref
                      .child("/Exam/$_selectedexam/$_selectedsemester")
                      .get(),
                  builder:
                      (context, AsyncSnapshot<DataSnapshot> asyncSnapshot) {
                    if (asyncSnapshot.hasError)
                      return Text("Error: ${asyncSnapshot.error}");
                    if (!asyncSnapshot.hasData)
                      return const CircularProgressIndicator();

                    return DropdownButton<String>(
                      isExpanded: true,
                      items: asyncSnapshot.data!.children
                          .map((snap) => DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: snap.key,
                              child: Text(snap.key.toString())))
                          .toList(),
                      value: _selectedcourse,
                      onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                        setState(() {
                          _selectedcourse = newValue!;
                          print(_selectedcourse);
                        });
                      },
                    );
                  }),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

> Here is the complete code. I want to display data in a dependent dropdown but I got error kindly tell me how to solve it. In first drop down I display exam(spring and fall) if user clicks on spring it displays related semesters in another drop down. It works fine for first time but when I change drop down value error shown Thanks

[drop downs structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qiVm.png)

[error image after changing first drop down value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUFzM.png)

Answer (score 0):

From what i see is when you have selected the first dropdown and based on that you have selected the second dropdown. And now you change the first dropdown the second dropdown will give error. for that you have to do the following thing in the code.

```
FutureBuilder (
            future: ref.child("/Exam/$_selectedexam").get(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DataSnapshot> asyncSnapshot) {
              if (asyncSnapshot.hasError)
                return Text("Error: ${asyncSnapshot.error}");
              if (!asyncSnapshot.hasData)
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();

              return DropdownButton<String> (
                items: asyncSnapshot.data!.children
                    .map((snap) => DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: snap.key, child: Text(snap.key.toString())))
                    .toList(),
                value: _selectedsemester,
                onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                      _selectedexam = null;/*or you can check this as well _selectedexam = '';  */ // make it null for empty
                    _selectedsemester = newValue!;
                    print(_selectedsemester);
                  });
                },
              );
            }),
```

you can check this and let me know if it works for you.

End Solution:
Main cause is when the item is changed the dependent dropdown should be bought to initial state.

Comment: I apply it but again i am getting error when I change the drop down value

Comment: error is --->_FutureBuilderState<DataSnapshot>#cb925):
Assertion failed:
..\…\material\dropdown.dart:882
items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1
"There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: semester 4. \nEither zero or 2 or
more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value"
The relevant error-causing widget was:
  FutureBuilder<DataSnapshot>

Comment: Just make sure the dropdown items _selectedexam and selectedsem are optional.

Comment: can you please add the full code so that i can let you know the exact cause.

Comment: I added complete code

Comment: Ok let me see it